# Binding property to a CustomControl

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding

After reading a lot about binding and trying a lot of examples, i can not achieve my goal.

I have a user control with two textblocks

```
<TextBlock x:Name="Hex_Value_00" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Cursor="Hand">00</TextBlock>
<TextBlock x:Name="Hex_Value_01" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Cursor="Hand">00</TextBlock>
```

And in the code-behind I have the next:

```
Private s_RawString As String

Public Shared ReadOnly RawStringProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("RawString", GetType(String), GetType(USerControl))

Public Property RawString As String
    Get
        Return s_RawString
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        SetValue(RawStringProperty, value)
        s_RawString = value
        ParseRawString() ' This splits the raw string in two
    End Set
End Property
```

I saw a lot of examples on how to bind a custom property to a text property of a single item. However, here I need to bind to the rawstring and then show half of it in one textblock and half in the other.

Comment: *What* do you want to bind to the raw string? The other part is easy: To display two halves of it in two TextBlocks, just create one readonly String property for each half (I'll call those properties `FirstHalf` and `SecondHalf`), and assign the halves appropriately inside ParseRawString(). Then bind them: `<TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstHalf, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />`

Comment: Thank your for your reply! I managed to do the binding. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I added a new post with more information with the problem and full source code of it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37846474/update-usercontrol-ui-with-a-binding-property

Comment: Please add that information to this post, and delete the other one. There is an edit button at the bottom left of the post.Thanks!