# Update UserControl UI with a binding property

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding, user-controls

I have a UserControl with a property that can be binded to. This property needs to update the UserControl UI. The UserControl has two textblocks and the property needs to update one textblockwith half of the string and the other textblock with the other half.

UserControl XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="HexView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LearningWPF"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtOne" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,10,0,0">Hola</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtTwo" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="120,10,0,0">Adios</TextBlock>

</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

UserControl CodeBehind (VB)

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class HexView

Private s_Rawstring As String

Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
End Sub

Public Shared ReadOnly RawStringProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("RawString", GetType(String), GetType(HexView))
Public Property Rawstring As String
    Get
        Return GetValue(RawStringProperty)
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        SetValue(RawStringProperty, value)
        Parse()
    End Set
End Property

Private Sub Parse()
    txtOne.Text = Rawstring.Substring(0, Rawstring.Length / 2)
    txtTwo.Text = Rawstring.Substring(Rawstring.Length / 2)
End Sub
End Class
```

If I set the property like

```
hexview.rawstring = "This is a sample property"
```

the UserControlUI is updated because it uses the setter accesor and executes the method Parse(). However using databind does not.

bAny feedback will be appreciate.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ryan Flohr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1322678/ryan-flohr)'s answer would do what you want, but since he mentioned the long-winded method, I guess I would put up the long-winded method as well. The long-winded method is definitely the recommended way to do it.

Code behind:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class HexView

Private s_Rawstring As String

Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
End Sub

Public Shared ReadOnly RawStringProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("RawString", GetType(String), GetType(HexView), New PropertyMetadata(New PropertyChangedCallback(AddressOf RawStringPropertyChanged)))
Public Property Rawstring As String
    Get
        Return GetValue(RawStringProperty)
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        SetValue(RawStringProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property

Private Shared Sub RawStringPropertyChanged(ByVal d As DependencyObject, ByVal e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    Dim control As HexView = CType(d, HexView)
    control.Parse()
End Sub

Public Shared ReadOnly ParsedStringOneProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ParsedStringOne", GetType(String), GetType(HexView), New PropertyMetadata(String.Empty))
Public Property ParsedStringOne As String
    Get
        Return GetValue(ParsedStringOneProperty)
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        SetValue(ParsedStringOneProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property

Public Shared ReadOnly ParsedStringTwoProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ParsedStringTwo", GetType(String), GetType(HexView), New PropertyMetadata(String.Empty))
Public Property ParsedStringTwo As String
    Get
        Return GetValue(ParsedStringTwoProperty)
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        SetValue(ParsedStringTwoProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property


Private Sub Parse()
    ParsedStringOne = Rawstring.Substring(0, Rawstring.Length / 2)
    ParsedStringTwo = Rawstring.Substring(Rawstring.Length / 2)
End Sub
End Class
```

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="HexView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LearningWPF"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
  <TextBlock x:Name="txtOne" Width="100" Height="100"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,10,0,0"
           Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:HexView}},Path=ParsedStringOne}"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtTwo" Width="100" Height="100"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="120,10,0,0"
           Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:HexView}},Path=ParsedStringTwo}" />

</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: This is a good answer, however, there is a small bug. In the xaml, since you're binding to a Dependency Property on the code behind, you need to specify the Binding as a RelativeSource, otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: I edited your answer, and StackOverflow said it will be visible once somebody peer reviews it.

Answer (score 2):

When you access a Dependency Property using a Binding, the code behind "Get" and "Set" don't actually get called. The get'r and set'r are simply a wrapper around the "GetValue()" and "SetValue()" as a convenience for code-behind use.

**My short answer to your question is the following code changes to at least get it working in its current form:**

Leverage the PropertyChangedCallback delegate on your Dependency Property and have it call the "Parse()" method.

```
Public Shared ReadOnly RawStringProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("RawString", GetType(String), GetType(HexView), New PropertyMetadata(New PropertyChangedCallback(AddressOf RawStringPropertyChanged)))
Public Property Rawstring As String
    Get
        Return GetValue(RawStringProperty)
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        SetValue(RawStringProperty, value)

    End Set
End Property

Private Shared Sub RawStringPropertyChanged(ByVal d As DependencyObject, ByVal e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    Dim control As HexView = CType(d, HexView)
    control.Parse()
End Sub
```

**My proper answer to your question is a little more long-winded:**

While it is legal, you should generally avoid referencing controls by name in your code-behind. For the two strings, you should have dependency properties for each, and then bind the textboxes to them.

I hope this helps!

Comment: The solution with the PropertyChangeCallback works. Thank you everybody. Altough, what are the pro's and con's of referencing a control on the UI of the UserControl? Why is it a better aproach using dependency properties on the controls? Also, I ask I simplified the problem with two textblocks, while in reality I am talkign about 256...Does it changes the approach? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Write an IValueConverter , which will do the work for you.

```
class ParseStringConv : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (parameter.ToString() == "Left")
                return value.ToString().Substring(0, value.ToString().Length / 2);

            return value.ToString().Substring(value.ToString().Length / 2);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Usage :

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource ParseConv}, ConverterParameter='Left'}" />

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource ParseConv}, ConverterParameter='Right'}" />
```

Pass the appropriate `ConverterParameter`.

Comment: In my humble opinion, I don't feel like this answer gets to the core issue of the question. The issue was that there is a "Parse" method to be called upon setting the DependencyProperty, however, this "Parse" method only gets called if the DependencyProperty is set using the code behind, not the binding. I don't see how using a ValueConverter is appropriate here.

Comment: @RyanFlohr Using Converter is the right way to go here in this particular case.

Comment: Actually it would work. @RyanFlohr
This removes the need to use the Parse() method altogether.

Comment: There are pros and cons to each method. The DependencyProperty method would expose the two additional DependencyProperties to the person using `HexView`, which they could directly bind to, and change the value of the textblocks unexpectedly. Using converter would prevent this problem, but you would have a converter that you probably would be used just for this control, and sometimes it is difficult to decide which folder to place the converter in.